# Macro that deletes duplicates given particular parameters

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I am given a data sheet with executed trades. The problem is that each trade is given a buy side and a sell side which duplicates the information I want to analyze. The commonality amongst the duplicates is that they have the same order number. Example:

```
**Order Number**       **Side**
20                       Buy
20                       Sell
25                       Buy
30                       Sell
30                       Buy
25                       Sell
```

Initially I thought of using "Remove Duplicates" but that does not delete the entire row and rather just the cell. How can I create a macro that Searches the order number column for duplicates and if they are found --> one row is deleted?

Comment: Turn it into an Excel table and filter on Side column? Or do the same with pivottable? You can use functions like Aggregate to work with filtered lists.

Comment: Just out of interest, but why do you need a macro for this? A helper column with the right formula will give you exactly what you need (and there are other options as well, like @QHarr pointed out). Anyway, there is a rich variety of common questions around SO and the net. if you want a macro. That's a good starting point ;)

Comment: If "Remove Duplicates" is only removing one cell then you're not using it properly.  It's a good idea to check out the documentation of feature you aren't completely familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using VBA, you can actually just use "Remove Duplicates" by simply selecting the column that you want to use to delete the rows.

You can find a great explanation about how to do this here:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3421-excel-delete-rows-based-on-duplicates-in-one-column.html